# Can't std::cout a max_element function

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to find the biggest prime factor for 600851475143.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(long long int number) {
    if (number < 2)
        return false;
    if (number > 2 && (number % 2) == 0)
        return false;
    for (long long int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        if ((number % i) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    vector<long long int> myVectorOfPrimes;
    myVectorOfPrimes.push_back(1);
    myVectorOfPrimes.push_back(0);
    for(long long i = 2; i < 600851475143; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            myVectorOfPrimes.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    auto value = max_element(myVectorOfPrimes.cbegin(), myVectorOfPrimes.cend());
    cout << value;
}
```

I expect the max_element function to be able to find the biggest prime factor in the myVectorOfPrimes, find its data type, then cout it. Instead, I get the error E0349: no operator "<<" matches these operands, and Error: C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type '_FwdIt' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Couldn't you just find the first prime, searching backwards?

Comment: Zero is not a prime number, much less a factor of any other number.

Comment: Adding the numbers 1 and 0 shouldn't affect max_element though

Comment: It doesn't, but a container called `myVectorOfPrimes` containing `0` and `1` is unexpected.

Comment: Just rename it `myVectorOfPrimesAndOneAndZeroJustBecause`.

Answer (score 3):

The `std::max_element` function returns an iterator to the max element. You have to write:

```
cout << *value;
```

(You'll probably want to change the name of the variable.)

You can also get the index of the max element by subtracting the begin iterator from the iterator that `max_element` returns.